# Run code after iteration is done

Tags: python, python-3.x

Perhaps I am thinking to difficult but I want to know if it possible to execute code after the `for` loop is finished?

I need a mechanism that knows that the loop is finished and execute code when the for loop is finished.

Simple example:

```
numbers = ['1','2','3','4','5']
length_numbers = len(numbers)

for i in range(0, length_numbers):
    print(i)
    if i == length_numbers + 1:
        print("yep list is finished and execute code below")
        # .... <-- code will be placed here
```

This will not work because the `i` value will never become the value 5. I am sure there is an easy way to fix this. Can anyone tell me how I could achieve that? Perhaps I should change the construction and not use a `for` loop?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question... Code placed after the `for` loop __will__ be executed after the `for` loop is finished.

Comment: Put a code outside of loop? Code right outside of loop with be executed as soon as loop is finished - it's a basic premise of all programming languages.

Comment: I think op want something like atexit() of for loop

Comment: @AlokThakur and how's that changing a problem?

Comment: @Rogalski Sorry you are right. I thought that the code will be executed even if the loop is still running. I am just starting to learn python and I thought it worked different. Thanks for your explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in python the numbering system starts at 0, if you want the code you have written above to work you need to change the `if i == length_numbers + 1` to a minus 1 - `if i == length_numbers - 1` and the code will work as you want it to.

So for your example:

```
numbers = ['1','2','3','4','5']
length_numbers = len(numbers)

for i in range(0, length_numbers):
    print(i)
    if i == length_numbers - 1: # change to minus here
        print("yep list is finished and execute code below")
        # .... <-- code will be placed here
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I want. I thought it was an easy quick fix. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `else` statement.

```
for i in xrange(10):
    #loop body
    pass
else:
    #do this when loop is completed without any break
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

How about the simple way?

```
numbers = ['1','2','3','4','5']
length_numbers = len(numbers)

for i in range(0, length_numbers):
    print(i)

print("yep list is finished and execute code below")
```

Answer (score 2):

if your numbers is **fixed** then below code may work.

Just replace

```
    if i == length_numbers + 1:
```

with

```
    if i == length_numbers - 1:
```

Even if numbers is not fixed. You just get its length using len() function & as you are starting loop from zero you can check value of i

```
    length_num = len(numbers) # get the length of numbers

    if i == length_num - 1  # check if i reached last val
        # stuff you want to do
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Why don't You just use `if i == length_numbers - 1:` so the code is executed at the end of the last iteration (mind that `range(0, length_numbers) = [0, 1, ..., length_numbers - 1]`)? Or just place the code after the `for` loop.

like this:

```
numbers = ['1','2','3','4','5']
length_numbers = len(numbers)
for i in range(0, length_numbers):
    print(i)
    if i == length_numbers - 1:
        print("yep list is finished and execute code below")
        # .... <-- code will be placed here
```

or this:

```
numbers = ['1','2','3','4','5']
length_numbers = len(numbers)
for i in range(0, length_numbers):
    print(i)
print("yep list is finished and execute code below")
# .... <-- code will be placed here
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make if len(numbers) == i + 1: